# C# / C++ Asynchronous reverse pinvoke?

Tags: c++, c, asynchronous, pinvoke, native

I need to call C# code from a native C/C++ .dll **asynchronously**.

While searching how to do I found that I could create a C# delegate and get a function pointer from it, which I would use inside my native code.

The problem is that my native code needs to run **asynchronously**, i.e in a separate thread created from the native code, which means that the native code called from the C# will return to C# before the delegate is called.

I read in another SO question that someone had trouble with this, **despite what the MSDN says**, because his delegate was garbage collected before it gets called, due to the asynchronous nature of his task.

My question is : is it really posible to call a C# delegate using a function pointer from a native code running in a thread that was created inside the native code ? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is a universal bug and not specific to asynchronous code.  It is just a *bit* more likely to byte in your case since you never have the machinery behind [DllImport] to keep you out of trouble.  I'll explain why this goes wrong, maybe that helps.

A delegate declaration for a callback method is always required, that's how the CLR knows now to make the call to the method.  You often declare it explicitly with the *delegate* keyword, you might need to apply the [UnmanagedFunctionPointer] attribute if the unmanaged code is 32-bit and assumes the function was written in C or C++.  The declaration is important, that's how the CLR knows how the arguments you pass from your native code need to be converted to their managed equivalent.  That conversion can be intricate if your native code passes strings, arrays or structures to the callback.

The scenario is *heavily* optimized in the CLR, important because managed code inevitably runs on an unmanaged operating system.  There are a *lot* of these transitions, you can't see them because most of them happen inside .NET Framework code.  This optimization involves a **thunk**, a sliver of auto-generated machine code that takes care of making the call to foreign method or function.  Thunks are created on-the-fly, whenever you make the interop call that uses the delegate.  In your case when C# code passes the delegate to your C++ code.  Your C++ code gets a pointer to the thunk, a function pointer, you store it and make the callback later.

"You store it" is where the problem starts.  The CLR is unaware that you stored the pointer to the thunk, the garbage collector cannot see it.  Thunks require memory, usually just a few handful of bytes for the machine code.  They don't live forever, the CLR automatically releases the memory when the thunk is no longer needed.

"Is no longer needed" is the rub, your C++ code cannot magically tell the CLR that it no longer is going to make a callback.  So the simple and obvious rule it uses is that the thunk is destroyed when the delegate object is garbage collected.

Programmers forever get in trouble with that rule.  They don't realize that the life-time of the delegate object is important.  Especially tricky in C#, it has a lot of syntax sugar that makes it *very* easy to create delegate objects.  You don't even have to use the *new* keyword or name the delegate type, just using the target method name is enough.  The lifetime of such a delegate object is *only* the pinvoke call.  After the call completes and your C++ code has stored the pointer, the delegate object isn't referenced anywhere anymore so is eligible for garbage collection.

Exactly *when* that happens, and the thunk is destroyed, is unpredictable.  The GC runs only when needed.  Could be a nanosecond after you made the call, that's unlikely of course, could be seconds.  Most tricky, could be never.  Happens in a typical unit test that doesn't otherwise calls GC.Collect() explicitly.  Unit tests rarely put enough pressure on the GC heap to induce a collection.  It is a *bit* more likely when you make the callback from another thread, implicit is that other code is running on other threads that make it more likely that a GC is triggered.  You'll discover the problem quicker.  Nevertheless, the thunk *is* going to get destroyed in a real program sooner or later.  Kaboom when you make the callback in your C++ code after that.

So, rock-hard rule, you **must** store a reference to the delegate to avoid the premature collection problem.  Very simple to do, just store it in a variable in your C# program that is declared `static`.  Usually good enough, you might want to set it explicitly back to null when the C# code tells your C++ code to stop making callbacks, unlikely in your case.  Very occasionally, you'd want to use `GCHandle.Alloc()`instead of a static variable.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to make such a detailed answer. I'm unfamiliar with C#, so let alone the inter operability stuff. If i understand well what you wrote, storing a reference to the delegate will prevent it from being collected, so the "thunk" (whatever this is) will remain alive too, and i will be able to make the call to the delegate from the thread even after the native function that started the thread has returned to C# right ?

Comment: I'm never that keen on somebody condensing one of my posts into a single sentence.  But, yeah, that's it.

Comment: This is new to me so i'm just trying to synthesize the idea for it to be easier to understand and remeber for me.

Comment: Fair call.  Just remember that your C++ code cannot do anything to solve this problem.  So if you get a "your code crashes my program" complaint then point the C# programmer at this answer.  He'll have a use for the long answer to get him off your back.

Comment: @Hans Passant -- when you say "thunk", do you mean the Reverse PInvoke Stub? I see that the Reverse PInvoke Stub is only created once per my delegate type, but somehow the CLR knows which instance to call. So I digged into it and there seems to be something like "GetStubContext" in the MSIL which seems to be thread-specific and is able to know which instance I'm referring to because it seems the stack captures the instance in some memory.

If my hypothesis is correct, that would mean async calls would not work. So either I'm wrong (happy to be) or async calls donot work?

Comment: These callbacks could not possibly more async.  Made whenever native code runs, activated for whatever reason.  Click the Ask Question button if you want somebody to dig through the CLR source to find the relevant code.